# How change excel 2007 document orientation to landscape by OpenXML sdk

Tags: excel-2007, openxml-sdk, spreadsheetml

I need help with changing excel 2007 document orientation to landscape. I have not found any helpful information about this. I am using OpenXML SDK for this.
The only thing I have found: when I create a new Worksheet I should set PageSetup() { Orientation = OrientationValue.Landscape}; But this doesn't help. 
Can anybody help with this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track with the OrientationValue.Landscape.  You just need to loop through all worksheets and set the orientation attribute on the PageSetup element in order to set all worksheets to landscape:

```
    public static void SetLandscape(SpreadsheetDocument document)
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
            IEnumerable<string> worksheetIds = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Select(w => w.Id.Value);
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart;
            foreach (string worksheetId in worksheetIds)
            {
                worksheetPart = ((WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(worksheetId));
                PageSetup pageSetup = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<PageSetup>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (pageSetup != null) 
                {
                     pageSetup.Orientation = OrientationValues.Landscape;
                }
                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
            }
            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        }
```

The pattern I use to manipulate documents is to first open excel and create a blank document and save it.  I then use my code to open that document and doing any work I need to it.  This way I don't have to be bothered with creating a the elements and making sure things are in the right place.  The code I use to achieve this is here:

```
public byte[] Export(string pathToExcelFile)
    {
        // Open the file from the drive
        byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToExcelFile)
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true))
            {
                // Do all work on excel doc here
                SetLandscape(spreadsheetDoc);

                // Save all the changes
            }

            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

So here I open the file from the drive into a memory stream so I can perform all the edits in memory.  I then pass that document in the SetLandscape method and it will set the landscape property on all three sheets (3 sheets since that is the default for a blank excel 2007 document). I then save my changes and return the stream as a byte array.  I do this so the file can be downloaded.  I recommend that you create a blank file and open it into memory like this instead of manually trying to build up the file from scratch.  That would explain why you are getting so many null pointers.

Comment: Hi amurra!
Thank you for answer! I tried It and It falls with NullReferenceException "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on row pageSetup.Orientation = OrientationValues.Landscape;
Why does It happened?
Thank you.

Comment: Forgot to add a check for null around pageSetup. The one thing is I believe the PageSetup element is required to be a descendant of Worksheet so it shouldn't ever throw a null pointer, but to be safe the if check is added. I tried the code in my project and it set the orientation to landscape.  If you still have problems post the code you are using and I can look at it.

Comment: I tried your solution and It doesn't work. =( After calling method SetLandscape() I can't open my document. It says that document is broken. Why does It happen? 
Bug with null PageSetup I fixed with adding code new PageSetup() while creating new worksheet. Maybe you can post full code snippet for creation Excel document and changing orientation.
Thank you.

Comment: @Paul - I posted the code you requested. It works for me locally. Does this help you or answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

I solve with:

```
PageSetup pageSetup = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<PageSetup>().FirstOrDefault();
if (pageSetup == null)
{
    pageSetup = new PageSetup();
    pageSetup.Orientation = OrientationValues.Landscape;
    worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(pageSetup);
}
```

Comment: I much prefer this option.  Learning how to use the SDK and OpenXML format is much better than constructing things from a template, in the long run.