# Setting the margin of word document in c# using Open XML

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I have created a Word document using Open Xml. The document gets created when a button in a web part is created. Currently I have created a table in the document to test that it works. What I want to do now is to be able to set the page margins for the newly created documnet.

I am not sure how to proceed. What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

(below is the current code I have that creates the word document with a table inside)

---

```
void GenerateBadges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Creating a word document using the the Open XML SDK 2.0
    WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Create(@"C:\Users\Daniel.Perez
    \Documents\sample-badges.docx", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

    //create a paragraph
    MainDocumentPart mainDocumenPart = document.AddMainDocumentPart();
    mainDocumenPart.Document = new Document();
    Body documentBody = new Body();
    mainDocumenPart.Document.Append(documentBody);

    //adding a table to the document
    Table table = new Table();
    TableProperties tblProps = new TableProperties();
    TableBorders tblBorders = new TableBorders();

    tblBorders.TopBorder = new TopBorder();
    tblBorders.TopBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single);

    tblBorders.BottomBorder = new BottomBorder();
    tblBorders.BottomBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single);

    tblBorders.RightBorder = new RightBorder();
    tblBorders.RightBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single);

    tblBorders.LeftBorder = new LeftBorder();
    tblBorders.LeftBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single);

    tblBorders.InsideHorizontalBorder = new InsideHorizontalBorder();
    tblBorders.InsideHorizontalBorder.Val = BorderValues.Single;

    tblBorders.InsideVerticalBorder = new InsideVerticalBorder();
    tblBorders.InsideVerticalBorder.Val = BorderValues.Single;

    tblProps.Append(tblBorders);
    table.Append(tblProps);

    TableRow row;
    TableCell cell;

    //first table row
    row = new TableRow();
    cell = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Table to hold the badges"))));

    TableCellProperties cellProp = new TableCellProperties();
    GridSpan gridSpan = new GridSpan();
    gridSpan.Val = 11;

    cellProp.Append(gridSpan);
    cell.Append(cellProp);
    row.Append(cell);
    table.Append(row);

    //second row
    row = new TableRow();
    cell = new TableCell();
    cell.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Inner Table"))));
    row.Append(cell);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        row.Append(new TableCell(new Paragraph (new Run(new Text(i.ToString())))));
    }

    table.Append(row);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        row = new TableRow();
        row.Append(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(i.ToString())))));

        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            row.Append(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text((i * j).ToString())))));
        }
        table.Append(row);
    }


    //add the table to the document - table needs to be wired into the for each loop above
    documentBody.Append(table);

    //Saving/Disposing of the created word Document
    document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
    document.Dispose();
}
```

---

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried PageMargin? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.pagemargin.aspx

Comment: this shows how to do it in open Xml, I am interested in doing via code behind using c#

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430437/open-xml-sdk-page-margins

Comment: "PageSetup" as mentioned in the example is not being recognised visual studio 2010 any ideas?

Answer (score 18):

Although the question is quite old and left unanswered, just to complete the thread and to help those who might land on this page later, I am posting the resolved code:

```
SectionProperties sectionProps = new SectionProperties();
PageMargin pageMargin = new PageMargin() { Top = 1008, Right = (UInt32Value)1008U, Bottom = 1008, Left = (UInt32Value)1008U, Header = (UInt32Value)720U, Footer = (UInt32Value)720U, Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U };
sectionProps.Append(pageMargin);
mainPart.Document.Body.Append(sectionProps);
```

Note: You may convert Open XML to C# code using "Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool". Just open any open XML format file (document/spreadsheet etc) in the tool and click "Reflect Code" toolbar button.